# Navigation Drawer unable to take to specific location in maps fragment in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

OK, so i have a map in a fragment and a navigation drawer in my app. The map loads when the app is run and points to the current location. Now I have added few places in my navigation list with their lats and longs. Now all i want to do is whenever i click one of such places in my navigation drawer it takes me to that place without loading the map fragment again and also without changing the current set markers on the map.

Here's the SelectItem method which is called on each item click in the navigation drawer. This method exists in the MainActivity of my application

```
   public void SelectItem(int possition) {

Fragment fragment = null;
Bundle args = new Bundle();

fragment = new MAPFragment();


Log.e("In main activity","Lets see what happens");



String[] coords = dataList.get(possition).getGeo().split(",");
Double c1 = new Double(Double.valueOf(coords[0])); 
Double c2 = new Double(Double.valueOf(coords[1]));



fragment.setArguments(args);



FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
final Fragment existingFragment = frgManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);


if(existingFragment !=null){

    ((receiveData)existingFragment).navigateToNewLocation(c1,c2);
}
else
 frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}
```

Here's my map fragment...

```
 interface receiveData{
public void navigateToNewLocation(double lat, double lon);}
public class MAPFragment extends Fragment implements receiveData {
public  String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
public  String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";
public  String GEO = "39.933333,32.866667";

public void setParameters(double lat, double lon){
  navigateToNewLocation(lat, lon);
}
// Google Map
 private GoogleMap googleMap;
 ImageView ivIcon;
 TextView tvItemName;
 MapView mapView;


String[] coords = GEO.split(",");
Double c1 = new Double(Double.valueOf(coords[0]));
Double c2 = new Double(Double.valueOf(coords[1]));

public MAPFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container,
                false);
    Log.e("coords[0]",coords[0]);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return view;
 }


 /**
   * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
  * */
 public void initilizeMap() {
  if (googleMap==null){
    googleMap=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    Log.e("In MAPFragment","Before coords!=null");


    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(c1,c2)));


      LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
      String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
      Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

      if(location!=null){
          onLocationChanged(location);
      }

      googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

          @Override
          public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
          }
      });

    //checking
    if(googleMap==null){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }
 }

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}

 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Getting latitude of the current location
   double latitude = location.getLatitude();

  // Getting longitude of the current location
  double longitude = location.getLongitude();

  // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

  // Showing the current location in Google Map
  googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

  // Zoom in the Google Map
  googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

 }

@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
   }

 public void navigateToNewLocation(double lat, double lon){

  Log.e("INSIDE navigateToNewLoc","next is cam pos");
    // On clicking a user       
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
            new LatLng(lat,lon)).zoom(12).build();
     Log.e("INSIDE navigateToNewLoc","next is animateCam");
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

 }
  }
```

Right now with these code everytime i click on an item in navigation drawer, the app fails....i guess this happens because of the Class Cast Exception in this very line in SelectItem method

```
  ((receiveData)existingFragment).navigateToNewLocation(c1,c2);
```

Here's my log cat

```
    09-10 03:00:00.784: E/AndroidRuntime(31030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-10 03:00:00.784: E/AndroidRuntime(31030): Process: com.findmeWithdrawer, PID: 31030
    09-10 03:00:00.784: E/AndroidRuntime(31030): java.lang.ClassCastException:         com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to com.findmeWithdrawer.receiveData
    09-10 03:00:00.784: E/AndroidRuntime(31030):  at       com.findmeWithdrawer.MainActivity.SelectItem(MainActivity.java:205)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you create your fragment, try to query first if it already exists. For example:

```
final Fragment existingFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("myfragmentname");
```

If it doesn't exists then:

```
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment,"myfragmentname")
         .commit();
```

Then, pass your parameters to your fragment (whether newly instantiated or not) by implementing a method for receiving parameters (implement an interface):

```
 ((SomeInterface)existingFragment).SetParameters(blah1, blah2, blah3);
```

Your fragment definition implements this interface

```
  public class MAPFragment extends Fragment implements SomeInterface {
    public SetParameters(int blah1, int blah2, int blah3) {
       // do your stuff here...
```

Comment: Hey I have edited my code above...you method partly worked...but still a Class Cast Exception exists...and i dont know how to fix it
-------
      java.lang.ClassCastException:         com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to com.findmeWithdrawer.receiveData

Comment: What is the data type of existingFragment variable? Is it your MAPFragment class (that you wrote) or Google's MapFragment (com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment)? Try to add a LogCat tostring before the line that crashes (e.g. Log.i("yourtag", existingFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())

Comment: Hey I just added the LOG CAT data